# Vlookup a value from multiple sheets in same workbook

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

Trying to lookup a value from multiple sheets. The first code is working. But the code from `IF FUNCTION` is throwing an error -

> Type mismatch runtime error 13

after first lookup, for all `#NA` in the column E, i need to lookup the value in the second sheet.

```
Sub Vlookup()

' Vlookup Macro

    Worksheets("ORD_CS").Activate
    Dim LR As Long
    LR = Worksheets("ORD_CS").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Range("E2:E" & LR).Formula = Application.Vlookup(Range("M2:M" & LR), Worksheets("WSS").Range("A2:C999999"), 3, False)
    If Range("E2:E" & LR) = "" Then
       Range("E2:E" & LR) = Application.Vlookup(Range("M2:M" & LR), Worksheets("IBC").Range("C2:F999999"), 4, False)
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: you need to understand the difference between a single cell and a range. You can't compare a range like this `Range("E2:E" & LR) = ""`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First**, as mentioned by @teylyn, the first parameter of `Vlookup` is a single value, not a `Range`.

**Second**, you can't use `Range("E2:E" & LR).Formula`, but on the right side use `Application.Vlookup`. You have 2 options:

1. Use the `Value`, like `Range("E2:E" & LR).Value = Application.Vlookup...`
2. Use `Formula`, so you'll need to modify the right side: `Range("E2:E" & LR).Formula = "VLookup(..."` rest of the formula string.

**Third**, you need to trap the scenario if `Application.Vlookup` isn't able to find a match, otherwise it will throw you an error. You can do that by using:

```
If Not IsError(Application.Vlookup(.Range("M" & i).Value, Worksheets("WSS").Range("A2:C999999"), 3, False)) Then
```

Look at the code below, I used the `Value` option to look in both sheets.

***Code***

```
Option Explicit

Sub Vlookup()

' Vlookup Macro
Dim Sht As Worksheet
Dim LR As Long, i As Long

' set the worksheet object
Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ORD_CS")

With Sht
    LR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To LR
        ' check that Vlookup succesfully found a match
        If Not IsError(Application.Vlookup(.Range("M" & i).Value, Worksheets("WSS").Range("A2:C999999"), 3, False)) Then
            .Range("E" & i).Value = Application.Vlookup(.Range("M" & i).Value, Worksheets("WSS").Range("A2:C999999"), 3, False)
        Else ' Vlookup error
            .Range("E" & i).Value = ""
        End If
    Next i

    ' second loop, for empty cells from previous VLookup >> check in the second sheet
    For i = 2 To LR
        If .Range("E" & i).Value = "" Then
            ' check that Vlookup succesfully found a match
            If Not IsError(Application.Vlookup(.Range("M" & i).Value, Worksheets("IBC").Range("C2:F999999"), 3, False)) Then
                .Range("E" & i).Value = Application.Vlookup(.Range("M" & i).Value, Worksheets("IBC").Range("C2:F999999"), 3, False)
            Else ' Vlookup error >> raise an Error (like a log-file)
                .Range("E" & i).Value = "Couldn't find Value in both sheets!"
            End If
        End If
    Next i

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome !! Thanks a ton :)

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of a Vlookup must be a single value, not a range